# Detect last index of last chunk index in a chunked array

Tags: javascript

I need to fire off a function when the final index of final chunk is reached.
So for example

```
import { chunk } from 'lodash';
...
const chunked = chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2); // [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]

chunked.forEach((c, i) => {
 c.forEach((e, index) => {
  if (lastIndexOfLastChunk) {
    // do something() when the number 6 is reached
    something();
  }
 })
})
```

Any input is much appreciated. I know this is trivial but my brain is just not working today. Thanks all!

Comment: Why not just do `chunked.flat().pop()`? Or, if you don't need a reference to the last item, you can just call `something()` after the outer loop is completed, and then it'll only happen after everything is visited.

Comment: do you need the iteration?

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense since it's synchronous and you're calling something() in the end of the iteration so basically the call cannot mutate the arrays and affect the iterations. With the same success you could call it after the loops.

Answer (score 0):

You're 99% there. Just compare the outer and inner indices to the length of the chunk array and and the current chunk.

```js
const chunks = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]];

chunks.forEach((c, i) => {
 c.forEach((e, index) => {
  if (i === chunks.length - 1 && index === c.length - 1) {
    console.log(e)
  }
 })
})
```